# Converting a CATransform3D to an NSString

Tags: cocoa, calayer, catransform3d

I would like to be able to do something similar to `NSStringFromCGAffineTransform` for a `CATransform3D`. Are there any built in functions for this? Or ways of using existing APIs?

For example:

```
[[layer valueForKey:@"transform"] description]
```

nearly does it, but outputs the transform values as hex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CATransform3D` is a struct of `CGFloat`s, named `m11, m12, m13, ...` (right click on `CATransform3D` in Xcode and click "Jump to Definition"). Knowing this, you could create a function that will behave in a similar manner to the other `NSStringFromX()` functions.

```
NSString *NSStringFromCATransform3D(CATransform3D transform) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f]",
            transform.m11, transform.m12, transform.m13, transform.m14,
            transform.m21, transform.m22, transform.m23, transform.m24,
            transform.m31, transform.m32, transform.m33, transform.m34,
            transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43, transform.m44];
}
```